# Parse of invalid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

What happens if I use `JSON.parse` on an invalid string? Will it return an error code, or just break the script?

Is the behavior consistent across browsers? And for older browsers, does `json2.js` also have the same behavior?

Context: my script is collecting JSON strings from different sources and parses them. If a string is not well formed, I want my script to ignore it and move to the next.

Comment: What language & library are you using?

Comment: This can be answered very quickly by [reading the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will throw a catchable error. On proper browsers, [it is a `SyntaxError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). JSON2's implementation [mirrors this.](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L105)

Answer (score 8):

It will throw an error for any invalid syntax. If the JSON you're parsing can be malformed, use `try/catch`:

```
try {
  obj = JSON.parse(x)
} catch(e) {
  obj = {}
}
```